# "Broken" curve with ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a contour ellipse

```
ContourPlot[2.8034950798347694*10^8 + 346.6795282575007 x^2 - 
    929387.1591151787 y + 770.3723456790123 y^2 + 
    x (-623273.1898861742 + 1032.7522877535007 y) == 50000, {x, -600, 
    600}, {y, 0, 650}]
```

But the ellipse  appears to be "broken", is there any remedy for this? 
On doing the same thing on WolframAlpha I got a nice smooth ellipse though.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[
 2.8034950798347694*10^8 + 346.6795282575007 x^2 - 
   929387.1591151787 y + 770.3723456790123 y^2 + 
   x (-623273.1898861742 + 1032.7522877535007 y) == 50000, {x, -600, 
  600}, {y, 0, 650}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Don't forget the PlotPoints.